# Fonts not found issue

Tags: 2013, 404

I am adding my custom fonts to my SharePoint site. I have put my fonts in hive folder. This way I am able to load fonts much faster than any other way. Everything works fine except '.woff2' fonts file. The server returns below error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have checked that files are there. Here is my css code sample:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Effra-Regular';
  src: url('Effra-Regular.eot');
  src: url('Effra-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Effra-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Effra-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('Effra-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('Effra-Regular.svg#Effra-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

All other fonts files found except 'woff2'. Can you tell me what mistake I am doing there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with full url ex. http://server/_layouts/15/fontfolder/Effra-Regular.woff2

Comment: I have tried it. but still not solved.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I found out in IIS .woff2 was not present in MIME Types, added .woff2 in IIS MIME Type and it worked.

[Reference](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/25/fontawesome-fonts-and-mime-types-in-iis-and-other-web-servers)